# PHP file_get_content issue

Tags: php, json

so I have a webservice running on a Windows machine with a static IP adress and an open port. The webservice provides some json data. When accessing the IP adress and port from the browser the json is being displayed just fine.
[Sample json data from browser: [image: ]]

What I want to do now is fetch the data from this machines' service with php on a website.

I have the following php code on the website:

```
<?php
              $url = 'http://ip-of-the-machine:port/url?params';
              $result = file_get_contents($url);
              $json = json_decode($result);
              var_dump(json_decode($result, true))
?>
```

When I visit the site the code is on, the page is tuck loading infinetly.

When passing `'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'` as the url paramter, the sample json data from this website is being displayed.
In the php.ini file `allow_url_fopen` is set to "true".

So I assume that there is an issue with the source of my json data on my machine where the service is running. Do you have experiance with this issue? What is the problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of running the code in a webserver, triggered through a browser, run it on the commandline. Look at the debug outputs as well. Also, I believe URL paths are a configuration option that could be disabled, use `phpinfo()` to verify that. BTW: For a good question, you need a [mcve]. In this case, it should answer the question whether the `file_get_contents()`is even called, whether it blocks or later code blocks.

Comment: Hey. I can't answer to your direct issue, I have never used file_get_content in that purpose. To fetch json from an HTTP endpoint, i would rather use cURL (included in PHP but a bit... messy) or Guzzle (external lib, but easier to use)

Comment: Do you have access to the web service's code, to debug the issue from that end? If not, I would probably start by sending a User-Agent mimicking that of a current browser. If that doesn't help, I'd specify a read timeout of a couple of seconds next, and see what happens then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt When executing on the command line, the following error is thrown:
"failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in [...]" - But why? When opening the URL in the browser I can access it without a problem? Does it have something todo with the configuration of the server the php code to fetch the data runs on?

Comment: This sounds like a network / security issue to me, rather than anything to do with PHP: you are accessing it OK from a browser **on your local PC**, but unable to connect **from another server**. Most likely, the Windows server is only reachable from your connection via a local network or VPN, or you are whitelisted in its firewall rules.

Comment: Please add all relevant info to the question. Also, you haven't establish where precisely the error happens, as mentioned in my previous comment. Also, something I forgot to mention, you shouldn't use images of text here. It makes it hard to search and also unnecessarily difficult for people using screenreaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there was an internal problem with the hosting provider for the website where I run the PHP script that calls the URL to fetch the JSON.

They resolved the issue and now both cURL requests and `file_get_contents()` work just fine. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running this with [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) rather then file_get_contents. That allows for more debugging too.

Example:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://ip-of-the-machine:port/url?params';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); //Tell cURL that it should only spend 10 seconds trying to connect to the URL in question.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //A given cURL operation should only take 30 seconds max.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
$response=curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl); //retrieve all details from the http request thas was being made

//show that information in the browser
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
echo '</pre>';($info);

//show the actual respones from the browser
var_dump($response);

curl_close($curl);
```

Output in your browser (tested with an JSON **example** URL from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) would look like this:

[image]